# Using bash process substitution for a sudo command

Tags: bash

I would like to use bash process substitution for a sudo command.

For example, here's a non-sudo command that works for me:

```
$ cat <(echo "installed.txt")
installed.txt
```

And here's a sudo version of the command that does not work:

```
$ sudo cat <(echo "installed.txt")
cat: /dev/fd/63: Bad file descriptor
```

Reading the sudo man page, it seems that sudo closes all but the stdin/stdout/stderr file descriptors before running the command as root. This leads me to think that bash is creating the descriptor (and performing the process substitution) before running the sudo command.

I changed root's shell to bash (instead of sh default). I've tested that the command works fine when logged in as root. It only does not work via a sudo command.

What is the appropriate technique to achieve what I'm trying to do here? Eval, quoting, sudo flag, sudoers file mod, other?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try doing this in your shell :

```
$ sudo bash -c 'cat <(echo "installed.txt for UID=$UID")'
installed.txt for UID=0
```

Answer (score 14):

The behaviour described in the question is due to the design of `sudo`.

```
$ sudo cat <(echo "installed.txt")
cat: /dev/fd/63: Bad file descriptor
```

The error occurs because `sudo` has a default behaviour which closes file descriptors except for standard input, output and error. As described on the man page:

> By default, sudo will close all open file descriptors other than standard input, standard output and standard error when executing a command.

This behaviour can be overridden with the `-C` (or `--close-from`) option to specify a file descriptor number below which files should not be closed. However, use of this option must be permitted by an administrator: the following needs to be added to `/etc/sudoers`

```
 Defaults closefrom_override
```

With that in place, the command will work if `-C` is used:

```
$ sudo -C64 cat <(echo "installed.txt")
installed.txt
```

(here the number `64` was given because it was greater than the `63` in the error message).

Comment: will this be security risk?

Comment: I also wish to know more, espcially because I think that this answer is much better than spawning a shell to interpret a string that was built from outside the sudo. Meanwhile, I posted another answer for the case when process substitution is used to hide a password for example ( cc @Wang )

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo bash  -c 'cat <(echo "installed.txt")'
```

Comment: This is the accepted answer too, but it wasn't the earliest posting of it.

Comment: We were both frantically typing at the same time! You can't win them all. More to the point, _I_ can't win them all!

Comment: 3 minutes to write one line ? Huh ! =)

Answer (score 2):

In case you're asking for **process substitution for the security it brings**, like hiding a password from the process list, then you might better do it this way:

```
cat <(echo -n "$PASSWORD") | sudo cryptsetup ... --key-file -
```

Sure, the password is sent to `sudo` through its `stdin`, so the process substitution is not done *within* `sudo` as asked. And my answer becomes technically off topic.

I still hope it will help in this particular context, because the accepted answer comes with serious drawbacks: you need to build a properly quoted string, and then spawn a secondary shell to *interpret* it within the `sudo`.

This makes it not only slow, but also risky due to shell injection, environment variables and so.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is probably to put everything in a script, and run that script with `sudo`.

Comment: Everything is a one-liner; I'd like to avoid needing to do that.