# Process substitution not working with sudo

Tags: bash

From a **main** bash script run as `root`, I want to execute a subprocess using `sudo` as unpriviledge user `nobody`; that subprocess should `source` a file, which content is provided by the **main** script.

I am trying to solve this using bash process substitution. But I cannot manage to get this to work.

Can someone tell me why the following script, ...

```
#! /bin/bash
sudo -u nobody \
    bash -c 'source /dev/stdin || ls -l /dev/stdin /proc/self/fd/0 /proc/$$/fd/0; echo "A=$A"' \
        < <(echo "A=$(ls /root/.profile)")
```

... when run as `root`, produces the following ouput ?

```
root@raspi:~# ./test3.sh
bash: line 1: /dev/stdin: Permission denied
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root    15 Mar 20 20:55 /dev/stdin -> /proc/self/fd/0
lr-x------ 1 nobody nogroup 64 Aug 21 14:38 /proc/3243/fd/0 -> 'pipe:[79069]'
lr-x------ 1 nobody nogroup 64 Aug 21 14:38 /proc/self/fd/0 -> 'pipe:[79069]'
A=
```

I would expect reading from `stdin` to work because, as indicated by `ls -l`, read access to `stdin` is granted to `nobody` (which makes sense).

So why this does not work ? And is there any way to get this to work ?

Answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13672420/using-bash-process-substitution-for-a-sudo-command) did not help: as sample above shows, code in the `<(...)` bloc should access data that only `root` can.

Comment: BTW, this isn't just a class of issues encountered in process substitution across a privilege boundary. Attempting to reopen `/dev/stdout` and `/dev/stderr`, f/e, fails with services that inherited a UNIX socket writing to journald (which can't be opened with `open()`, but needs to be connected to with `connect()`); using direct references to the already-opened file descriptors avoids the problem in that case just as it avoids the problem in your current scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see why you have `Permission denied`, use `ls -lL`

```
sudo -u nobody \
    bash -c 'source /dev/stdin || ls -lL /dev/stdin /proc/self/fd/0 /proc/$$/fd/0; echo "A=$A"' \
        < <(echo "A=$(ls /root/.profile)")
```

To get around the error, use `cat |`

```
sudo -u nobody \
    bash -c 'cat | { source /dev/stdin || ls -lL /dev/stdin /proc/self/fd/0 /proc/$$/fd/0; echo "A=$A"; }' \
        < <(echo "A=$(ls /root/.profile)")
```

Comment: Indeed, `ls -l` clearly shows the problem. I'm still having trouble understanding, however, why `/proc/self/fd/0` is owned by `root` in a process running as `nobody`. Anyway, the `cat |` trick works, (making the device finally owned by `nobody` btw). Thanks.